# After restoring the geometry, the material is not displayed correctly

Tags: rendering, materials, uv, shaders, geometry

The original geometry with assigned material.

[image: Initial render]

Only faces deleted.

[image: remove and replace geometry]

Material flow artifacts after the faces were replaced.

[image: problematic render issue]

Is this a precedural rendered material issue?
Is there a setting or procedure to renormalize the faces?
I'm afraid I don't know enough to even ask the right question on this.
What is the cause and then how do you fix it?
Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Is your texture using UV coordinates? If so, you will have to UV unwrap again.

Comment: You used a UV sphere and then reconstructed faces.  Those new faces don't have any UV data

Comment: Try going to edit mode then uv unwrapping the faces

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: @JoeKel Also it seems like you need to shadesmooth the model to avoid facets shading.

Answer (score 1):

After editing existing unwrapped mesh always check UV for gaps, stretches and overlaps. In cases with gaps surrounded from all four sides on UV, to restore the same geometry and be sure that UV is not changed use Grid Fill:
[image]

1. In order to make a clean hole delete edge frame left over after faces removal
2. In Edit Mode select desired Edge Loop by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open Faces dialoge window and select  > *Grid Fill*

If topology of the mesh is more complex, we can edit the UV islands manually to make it correspond to our requirements.